# Performance optimization - add index to get max() of bigint on MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Working with MS SQL Server 2008. I have a heap table with no indexing at all and a high volume of data. I need to get the max() value of a bigint. What would take up the least amount of transaction log / disk space but let me get the result without having to do a table scan?

Answer (score 0):

Triggers.

If this is an insert-only table, you could create a ON INSERT trigger that updates a value in another table that stores your max int.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MaxValue ON Sales.Customer
AFTER INSERT
AS 
DECLARE @NewMax BIGINT;
SELECT @NewMax = Max(ImportantColumn) FROM Inserted;

UPDATE Sales.CustomerMax SET MaxValue = CASE WHEN @NewMax > MaxValue THEN @NewMax ELSE MaxValue END
```

GO

This is going to be much, much cheaper than maintaining a whole index when you only care about one value. However, it won't work if you are frequently updating or deleting from the table, as that would require triggers that perform expensive scans to find the next highest value.

Comment: Are triggers evil? Yes if they contain business logic. No if they are used for logging or to simulate specialized indexes as shown here.

Comment: So every insert or update to `Customer` will require a write lock on that single row in `CustomerMax`. Don't you think this will present an issue with concurrency and performance?

Comment: The alternative is a write lock on the B-Tree that's holding the ImportantColumn index. Plus a scan to find the right place to put the new record. Plus the RAM needed to keep the index in memory or more IO traffic to read the index from disk. Oh, and don't forget the possibility of page splits in that index. So yea, that write lock on that one column is going to be much, much cheaper than an index.

Comment: It's not about expense, it's about contention in the presence of high concurrency.  You don't usually lock a whole B-Tree (you'd lock a row or a page perhaps) but when everyone is trying to update that one row, that's it--
 everybody has to wait for everyone else. Seems like a recipe for deadlocks, too. Have you ever actually tried a mechanism like this one?

Comment: High contention yes, but this is also incredibly fast and there's no deadlock potential. The UPDATE statement on `Sales.CustomerMax` doesn't care about `Sales.Customer`, it is working off an independent varaible. You could even perform out of order updates to  `Sales.CustomerMax` and it wouldn't change the final result.

Comment: Unless of course your wrapped this all into a transaction. Then it could get messy.

Comment: Jonothan answer is correct with this strange 'no index' restriction - i have done this before with updates included. In order to accommodate updates you need a threshold of X max records (100?1000?) that you keep on that table, not just one. Threshold # depends from pragmatic updates logic. When a value updates higher enough to enter the max zone just enters and the lesser one gets out (if sum=max+1). When updated lower enough to get out just gets out and the threshold decreases. If the threshold decreases more than 90% then you need to refill with a table scan and a top X.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are doing updates and deletes. But you also know:

- For 5% of the records, ImportantColumn > X
- For 95% of the records, ImportantColumn <= X

You could then use a filtered index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_MaxValue ON Sales.Customer (ImportantColumn) WHERE ImportantColumn > X
```

This will eliminate 95% of the records from the index, meaning that you need far less RAM for said index plus most updates won't even touch it.

You will have to babysit this, adjusting X over time.